# Вывод определенной даты из производственного календаря

Tags: php, массивы, календарь

Нужно определить дату доставки исходя из статусов товара и времени до и после 13:00 по Екатеринбургу. Взял за основу производственный календарь, который отдает json данные, посмотреть пример можно тут: https://production-calendar.ru/get/ru/2024/json
**UPD: код переработал, изначально был другим.**

```
              <div class="calendar">
                    <?php
                        // Новый код от 20.01.2024 даты доставки
                        $dateEkat = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Yekaterinburg'));
                        $date_now = $dateEkat->format('d.m.Y');
                        $hours = $dateEkat->format('H:m');
                        // проходимся по массиву с датами, формируем новый массив, где в качестве ключа даты будет выступать
                        // h - holiday, w - work
                        foreach ($calendar['days'] as $item) {
                            if ($item['type_id'] == 2 || $item['type_id'] == 3 || $item['type_id'] == 4 || $item['type_id'] == 6) {
                                $item['type_id'] = 'h';
                                $new_arr[][$item['type_id']] = $item['date'];
                            }elseif($item['type_id'] == 1 || $item['type_id'] == 5){
                                $item['type_id'] = 'w';
                                $new_arr[][$item['type_id']] = $item['date'];
                            }
                        }
                        // проходимся в цикле по новому массиву с целью отрезать предыдущие даты, которые уже прошли,
                        // с учетом выходных, праздничных и т.д...
                        // формируем новый массив, для того, чтобы потом подсчитать какое кол-во элементов мы отрезали
                        foreach($new_arr as $key => $val){
                            if($val['h'] == $date_now || $val['w'] == $date_now){
                                break;
                            }
                            $count_date[] = $key;
                        }
                        // проходимся в цикле по новому массиву чтобы сформировать новый массив со всеми датами
                        foreach($new_arr as $key => $val){
                            $all_date[] = $val;
                        }
                        // отсекаем от нового массива предыдущие даты, получаем массив, который начинается с сегодняшней даты
                        $res_work = array_slice($all_date, count($count_date)+1);
                        // и снова проходимся в цикле чтобы сформировать только рабочие дни
                        foreach($res_work as $key => $item){
                            foreach($item as $k => $v){
                                if($k == 'h'){
                                    unset($k);
                                }
                                if($k == 'w'){
                                    $date[] = $v;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // ну и собственно выводим дату по ключу, учитываем что ключ начинает отсчет с 0
                        if($p['is_order'] == 'Y' && $p['is_exist'] == 'Y' && $time[0]['time'] >= $hours){
                            echo '<p>Доставка с <strong>'.$date[11].'</strong> при оплате до '.$time[0]['time'].'</p>';
                        }elseif($p['is_order'] == 'Y' && $p['is_exist'] == 'Y' && $time[0]['time'] < $hours){
                            echo '<p>Доставка с <strong>'.$date[12].'</strong> при оплате до '.$time[0]['time'].'</p>';
                        }elseif($p['is_exist'] == 'Y' && $p['is_order'] == 'N' && $time[0]['time'] >= $hours){
                            echo '<p>Доставка с <strong>'.$date[0].'</strong> при оплате до '.$time[0]['time'].'</p>';
                        }elseif($p['is_exist'] == 'Y' && $p['is_order'] == 'N' && $time[0]['time'] < $hours){
                            echo '<p>Доставка с <strong>'.$date[1].'</strong> при оплате до '.$time[0]['time'].'</p>';
                        }
                    // Новый код от 20.01.2024 даты доставки
                    ?>
              </div>
```

Такс... вот этот код работает вроде, если кому не сложно, подкиньте идеи, может можно как-то по другому сделать?

Comment: решение в лоб: сделай цикл и прибавляй по 1 на каждый рабочий день, пока не прибавишь нужное количество раз

Comment: Самое сложное, как я вижу - это сделать отсчет именно от сегодняшней даты, т.е. отрезать имеющийся начало массива с датами до сегодняшнего дня и уже с сегодняшнего начать манипуляцию с прибавлением нужного кол-ва дней к доставке.

Comment: Ничего сложного тут нет. ``date("z", mktime(0,0,0,17,1,2024))`` сразу дает номер дня в году (начиная с 0, т.е. 1 января - 0, 2 января - 1 итд.). И это сразу готовый индекс для days.

Comment: Не понимаю о чем речь... Суть такая: берем сегодняшний день, по нему нужно отсечь от производственного календаря предыдущие дни, иначе начнет выводить с 1 января, плюс к этому нужно именно по производственному учесть что только рабочие дни, в этом тоже засада. Если не сложно - коротенький пример приведи?

Comment: что значит "отсечь"? Вы к элементу массива по индексу умеете обращаться? Как учесть только рабочие дни я написал в самом первом комментарии.

Comment: Отсечь - значит отсечь, даты в производственном календаре начинаются с 01.01.2024 и имеют числовой индекс, как вы хотели по этому индексу отсечь дату до сегодняшней и учесть при этом рабочие дни я не понял.

Comment: У меня идея такая вот пришла в голову: бьем через $dayModify = explode('.', $item['date']); получаем только дату: $dayModify[0], и вот как-то нужно привести $dayModify[0] к массиву, а затем через array_slice($dayModify[0], $day_now); отсечем начиная с нужного дня $day_now = $dateEkat->format('d'); потом пересобрать обратно через implode() и на выходе получим массив дат начиная с сегодняшней. Но нифига не получается что-то...

Comment: Да объясните зачем вам отсекать даты, если можно просто обращаться по номеру к нужным дням?

Comment: Тоже самое прошу вас мне объяснить, как обратиться по номеру к нужным дням, учитывая при этом что дни бывают: рабочие, выходные и праздничные, плюс к этому каждый день - это новый день, он не статичный, а динамический. Приведите хотя бы пример рабочий, чтобы я понимал о чём вы говорите. Суть в том, чтобы к сегодняшнему рабочему дню прибавить ещё например 12 РАБОЧИХ дней.

Comment: Каждый новый день отличается от предыдущего на 1. Eсли сегодняшний день days[n], то завтрашний день будет days[n+1]. Как учитывать только рабочие дни я всё ещё написал в самом первом комментарии.

Comment: Все понятно, ладно, проехали... Помучаюсь - что-нибудь получится... наверное.

Comment: @Эникейщик Посмотри пожалуйста, переработал код, но вот как быть в таком случае с выходными и праздниками?

Comment: у меня возникла другая идея - отфильтровать исходный файл, оставить в нем только рабочие дни. Тогда можно будет просто прибавлять нужное число без всяких забот.

Comment: @Эникейщик Если запустишь этот код, он готовый, просто копи-паст к себе локально..., то увидишь что даты как раз отфильтрованы только по рабочим. Эх, видимо ты просто не до конца понимаешь задачу. Мне вот пришла такая идея - пересобрать массив так, чтобы в качестве ключа у даты было - work - рабочий день и holiday - выходной

Comment: Я понимаю задачу, я просто не вчитываюсь в твой код, а подсказываю идеи. Перед началом всего убедись, что date_now - рабочий день. Если нет, то прибавляй по одному, по не дойдёшь до рабочего, это будет новый date_now